# how to install mysql on centOS 6 without internet

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm trying to install Mysql on centOS and I have a constrain that I can't use internet.

I've spending a long time googling and searching the official documents.

However, all of them uses Yum that needs internet.

So, it doesn't work for me.....

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the best way to do this in your case is to download the files on another Computer with internet connection and then I guess copy the files on the target pc. If you download the packages compressed, be sure that you have an compression program like Gzip, Zip or Tar for your case. Hope that helps.